# How to interact with mssql from python?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

How to interact with mssql from python? I realy nead it to write my site.
I tried pyodbc

```
(

    pip install pyodbc

)
```

but cmd says there is an error in setup.py.
Pleese, help me!

P.S. I am using windows and mssql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have **Microsoft ODBC driver** for sql in Windows to make

```
pip install pyodbc
```

work.

Try to follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-2017#installing-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) and install required drivers.

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated Answer]**

Follow these steps to install pyodbc and pymssql in *64-bit Windows* with *Python 3.**

- Update **pip** tool:  `python -m pip install pip -U`
- Update **python setuptools** :  `python -m pip install setuptools -U`
- Install **pyodb** :  `pip3 install pyodbc -U`
- Download and install [MS Visual C++ 14.0 Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15). It's required for installing **pymssql**.

  - double click on downloaded file and select *Workloads → Visual C++ build tools* then in *optional features* tab select *Windows 10 SDK*(windows 8 user select *Windows 8 SDK*) and install.
- Install **pymssql**: `pip3 install pymssql -U`

---

**[Old Answer]**

One can also try these unofficial wheel files, if above method doesn't work.

You can install the same using the **unofficial** pyodbc wheel for python 3.* from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc), just download the appropriate wheel (*.whl) file form this link and install it using

```
pip install **downloaded_wheel_file_name**.whl
```

Note: Don't forget to change the **downloaded_wheel_file_name** with your **downloaded** wheel file's name.

Comment: Sorry, but I my computer doesn't know how to open them.

Comment: And trere aren't a whl file for 3.7.0 python, which I'm using.

Comment: @Kostya2007 No, the wheel files are there, for both Python 2.7 and 3.*, it may possible that the wheel files doesn't work for you since it requires MS Visual C++ 14.0 Build Tools.  See the updated answer, I just test the same on my Windows 10 (64-bit) with python 3.7.0 and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this @Kostya2007:   `pip install --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc pyodbc`

or

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/pyodbc/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip
```

depending on your Python version

or

```
easy_install pyodbc-3.0.7.win32-py2.7.exe
```